# nilpotent endomorphism and $Im(f)+Ker(f) \neq dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

If I have an endomorphism between vector spaces $f:V \rightarrow V$, such that $Im(f)+Ker(f) \neq dim(V)$, is this equivalent to $f$ being nilpotent?

Comment: No. Under the additional hypothesis that $\dim V$ is finite, this is only equivalent to $\operatorname{rk}f^2<\operatorname{rk}f$.

Comment: In dimension $2$ yes. Above, no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. Check out
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: okay, thank you!